# finding the value of radio button with jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

i have this code below to show different divs when i choose certain radio buttons:

```
if ($("input[@name='exerciseRB']:checked").val() == 'New') {
    $("#newExercise").show();
    $("#existingExercise").hide();
 }
 else {
    $("#newExercise").hide();
    $("#existingExercise").show();
 }
```

at first, i just had two radio buttons (both named exerciseRB and everything works fine.

Now, later in my web page i added two new radio buttons (with the name lessonRB).

The issue is that once i added these other new radio buttons when i look up this in firebug:

```
$("input[@name='exerciseRB']:checked")
```

i actually get an array back with both the exerciseRB item as well as the lessonRB item.  Its almost as if the

```
 @name='exerciseRB'
```

is being ignored. any ideas here?

Comment: are you sure the error is elsewhere!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the @ before name in your selector.

Answer (score 1):

@name='exerciseRB' should be  name=exerciseRB ie:

```
$("input[name=exerciseRB]:checked")
```